# Change Background Color of modal view

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to resent an viewcontroller as modal view in size .formSheet. The background color should not be grey transparent, it should be an blur effect.

How I cloud change the background color of view behind modal.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailViewController", bundle: nil)
if let modalViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? DetailViewController {
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
    modalViewController.item = item
    modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    modalViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

    self.present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you set any BG color in `DetailViewController ` controller?

Comment: Try  modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

Comment: If I use "modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom" the size is nit formSheet, that is an important thing.

Answer (score 2):

From the `viewWillAppear(:)` method of your `modalViewController`, you can access the `self.presentationController?.containerView` property. You can either change the background color or even add a blur effect view if you want.

Comment: Works Cool :) Thanks.

Comment: doesn't work for me. `ContainerView` is nil. iPad pro mini iOS12